# How to toggle two functions when needed? Vanilla JavaScript ES5

Tags: javascript

I'm making a menu, and I need to append child and remove it on the hamburger press.

It's easy to add/remove class, with toggle, however, how would you do it here? Vanilla JavaScript ES5

```
// MAIN NAVIGATION MENU TOGGLE
var siteNav = document.querySelector(".site-nav"),
    siteHamburger = document.querySelector(".site-header__toggle-button"),
    overlayDiv  = document.createElement('div'),
    menuOverlay = document.createElement('div');
    menuOverlay.className = 'overlay';

function openMenu() {
    siteNav.classList.add('is-active');
    siteHamburger.classList.add('is-active');
    document.body.appendChild(menuOverlay);
}

function closeMenu() {
    document.body.removeChild(menuOverlay);
    siteNav.classList.remove("is-active");
    siteHamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
}



siteHamburger.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
siteHamburger.addEventListener('click', closeMenu, false);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to use [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: I have two functions, right? openMenu and closeMenu. How can I toggle them on the hamburger click? Toggle the openMenu on first click, and on second closeMenu, 3rd open, 4th close, 5th etc..

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Please add a comment if not else please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a toggle function like:

```
function toggle() {

    if(siteNav.classList.contains("is-active")) {
        return closeMenu();
    }

    return openMenu();
}
```

and then instead of

```
siteHamburger.addEventListener('click', openMenu, false);
siteHamburger.addEventListener('click', closeMenu, false);
```

just call the toggle function

```
siteHamburger.addEventListener('click', toggle, false);
```

Comment: How would you do this with the append? The hardest part is to make this on when user clicks the menu, the hamburger should activate, the menu should activate, and we should add and append an overlay with opacity .5. 

When the user click the menu again, all of this should disapear, or perhaps if the user click the overlay as well. 

But I'm having problem on toggling the overlay for the most part.

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Well, how do you toggle appendChild? If you click the hamburger menu, appendChild, next time you click, removeChild, click again, appendChild, click again, removeChild, click again appendChild, click again removeChild. How do you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood how the code you wrote works. THis works!